# Neo4j: get all relations between queried nodes

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher, graph-databases

I want to make a cypher query that do below tasks:

1. there is a given start node, and I want to get all related nodes in 2 hops
2. sort queried nodes by hops asc, and limit it with given number
3. and get all relations between result of 1.

I tried tons of queries, and I made below query for step 1, 2

```
MATCH path=((start {eid:12018})-[r:REAL_CALL*1..2]-(end))
WITH start, end, path
ORDER BY length(path) ASC
RETURN start, collect(distinct end)[..10]
```

But when I try to get relationships in queried path with below query, it returns all relationships in the path :

```
MATCH path=((start {eid:12018})-[r:REAL_CALL*1..2]-(end))
WITH start, end, path
ORDER BY length(path) ASC
RETURN start, collect(distinct end)[..10], relationships(path)
```

I think I have to match again with result of first match instead of get relationships from path directly, but all of my attempts have failed.

How can I get all relationships between queried nodes?
Any helps appreciate, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

Something like this may work for you:

```
MATCH (start {eid:12018})-[rels:REAL_CALL*..2]-(end)
RETURN start, end, COLLECT(rels) AS rels_collection
ORDER BY
  REDUCE(s = 2, rs in rels_collection | CASE WHEN SIZE(rs) < s THEN SIZE(rs) ELSE s END)
LIMIT 10;
```

The `COLLECT` [aggregation function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) will generate a collection (of relationship collections) for each distinct `start/end` pair. The `LIMIT` clause limits the returned results to the first 10 `start/end` pairs, based on the `ORDER BY` clause. The `ORDER BY` clause uses `REDCUE` to calculate the minimum size of each path to a given `end` node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your query works fine, but limit has some problem. 'end' nodes are limited by 10 correctly with my query, but when I tested your query, it only displays 8 nodes. I think limit clause counts not only nodes but also relationships. Do you know how can I apply limit clause only for number of nodes?

Comment: If I understand what you want, my updated answer should work.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. Now I understand limit / order by clauses much better than before with your explanation. I'll try it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a result of your query, it limits end nodes correctly, but there is ordering problem. 
Actually I want to get nodes within 1 hop first in limit value, after then get 2 hop nodes. 
For example, if there are 10 nodes - 6 nodes in distance 1, 4 nodes in distance 2, and limit number is 8, then I want to aggregate 6 nodes in distance 1 first, and after then aggregate 2 nodes in distance 2. 
So I used length(path) ASC because of this requirement.
Could you give me an advice to handle it?

Comment: OK, nice problem. I have updated my answer yet again, The `COLLECT` function seems to mess up the ordering, so the new query no longer orders before doing the `COLLECT`, but afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer works very well :) I'm sorry I forgot voting, and now I voted up your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to understand your query but I can't figure out the logic of the statement using the 'Reduce' function. Could you explain detail please? ( I'm sorry to bother you)

Comment: That [REDUCE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) clause calculates the minimum size of all the paths in a given `rels_collection`.

Comment: Actually I thought 's' is an accumulator, and returned value from CASE expression accumulated to 's'. As you know each size(rs) is 1 or 2, and initial value of 's' is 2. And if first size(rs) is 1, then 's' will be 1 by the expression. After then second size(rs) is 2, then 's' will be 1 also. So I thought every next 's' value will be 1. But actually your query works very well contrary to my thinking. Which thing am I missing?

Comment: What you described is exactly how that `REDUCE` clause works. It is hard to say what you described in a single sentence, and perhaps I could have phrased it better :-).